# How can I reduce the number of interface methods in this generic jOOQ query

Tags: java, generics, jooq

```
    public interface BranchHistoryDao<B extends UpdatableRecord<B>, H extends UpdatableRecord<H>, P extends UpdatableRecord<P>, PH extends UpdatableRecord<PH>> extends TableDao<H> {
        default void saveHistoryForParentIds(Collection<Integer> parentIds) {
            HashMap<TableField<B, ?>, TableField<H, ?>> mappings = setUpHistoryMapping();

            List<TableField<H, ?>> historyFields = new ArrayList<>(mappings.size()); // ArrayLists will maintain order
            List<TableField<?, ?>> tableFields = new ArrayList<>(mappings.size());

            mappings.forEach((key, value) -> {
                historyFields.add(value);
                tableFields.add(key);
            });

            historyFields.add(historyToParentHistoryFK());
            tableFields.add(parentHistoryPK());

            List<Integer> latestHistories = jooq()
                .select(DSL.max(parentHistoryPK()))
                .from(parentHistoryTable())
                .groupBy(parentHistoryToParentFK())
                .fetchInto(Integer.class);

            jooq()
                .insertInto(
                    table(),
                    historyFields)
                .select(
                    jooq()
                        .select(
                            tableFields)
                        .from(baseTable())
                        .join(parentTable())
                        .on(parentPK().eq(baseToParentFK()))
                        .join(parentHistoryTable())
                        .on(parentHistoryToParentFK().eq(parentPK()))
                        .where(parentPK().in(parentIds))
                        .and(parentHistoryPK().in(latestHistories)))
                .execute();
        }

    HashMap<TableField<B, ?>, TableField<H, ?>> setUpHistoryMapping();

    TableField<B, Integer> basePK();

    Table<PH> parentHistoryTable();

    TableField<PH, Integer> parentHistoryPK();

    TableField<PH, Integer> parentHistoryToParentFK();

    TableField<H, Integer> historyToParentHistoryFK();

    Table<B> baseTable();

    TableField<B, Integer> baseToParentFK();

    Table<P> parentTable();

    TableField<P, Integer> parentPK();
}
```

I have generic jooq query that joins 4 tables together and I have a bunch of interfaces that grab certain attributes such as `TableField<B, Integer> basePK();` however; I believe functions like  `TableField<B, Integer> basePK();` and `parentHistoryTable();` are redundant because all the information I need is already defined in the generics.

But, the problem is I can't instantiate generics. If I could do `(new B()).getTable()` I could easily get `baseTable()` or `(new B()).getTable().field("id")` to get the basePK() but I can't due to type erasure. Does anyone have a solution to remove these redundant methods?

This is an example of what setUpHistoryMapping() would look like

```
@Override
public HashMap<TableField<MilestoneRecord, ?>, TableField<MilestoneHistoryRecord, ?>> setUpHistoryMapping() {
    HashMap<TableField<MilestoneRecord, ?>, TableField<MilestoneHistoryRecord, ?>> x = new HashMap<>();

    x.put(MILESTONE.LABEL, MILESTONE_HISTORY.LABEL);
    x.put(MILESTONE.BASELINE_DATE, MILESTONE_HISTORY.BASELINE_DATE);
    x.put(MILESTONE.IS_COMPLETE, MILESTONE_HISTORY.IS_COMPLETE);
    x.put(MILESTONE.DELETED_FLAG, MILESTONE_HISTORY.DELETED_FLAG);

    return x;
}
```

and

```
@Override
public Table<MilestoneRecord> baseTable() {
    return MILESTONE;
}
```

Comment: How many implementations does this interface have?

Comment: as of right now, 3. but it's a reuseable structure. The tables defined is a parent-child / parentHistory-childHistory structure

Comment: Oh, I see. "history" is used for some sort of technical / audit history table structure of your actual tables (e.g. "milestone"). Yeah, that makes sense then. Will look into this later.

Comment: @LukasEder right exactly! so everything from milestoneHistory is an exact copy from milestone plus a some additional foreign keys that point back to the parent table. The reason why I say methods such as `baseTable()` is redundant is because as you can see it's already type Table<MilestoneRecord> and pretty much the only possible option is `MILESTONE`